# window.location open in new tab

Tags: jquery, window.location

Here's my code that I use to make a whole div clickable:

```
$(".clickablediv").click(function(){
        window.location=$(this).find("a").attr("abc");
        return false;
        });
```

This works well but I want the link to open in a new tab.  My code is looking for hyperlink code in the div with the attribute abc added to it and this must be maintained. However, changing this to window.open loses the clickable div functionality.

How can I open this link in a new window? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
window.open($(this).find("a").attr("abc"));
```